# How to interpret JavaScript with Python

Tags: javascript, python

It is possible to run JavaScript with Python? There are any library that makes this possible?

I need to execute some JavaScript, I know that this is possible with some Java libraries, but I prefer Python.

Can someone give me a clue on this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check [spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It is not possible to call functions. I need to call some Javascript code that call some functions. There are no more options? Best Regards,

Comment: From the project summary: "This Python module allows for the implementation of Javascript classes, objects and functions in Python, as well as the *evaluation and calling of Javascript scripts and functions*".

Comment: of course it can call functions see def bind_callable(self, name, function) in http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/source/browse/trunk/spidermonkey.pyx

Answer (score 1):

If you already use PyQt and QWebView in it, displaying custom html, the function evaluateJavaScript of QWebFrame may be useful for you:

```
# Python
def runJavaScriptText(self, jsText):
   jsText = 'hello()'  # just to fit javascript example
   self.webView.page().currentFrame().evaluateJavaScript(jsText)


// Javascript
function hello() {
    alert('hello');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using spidermonkey would give you a tightier integration of your code, but as a workaround, you could make the javascript get run in a browser using Selenium remote-control:

http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/
(there are ways of doing that without needing a "physical" display for the browser, using VNC servers, for example)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see also from this article that are not many possibilities: http://blog.motane.lu/2009/06/18/pywebkitgtk-execute-javascript-from-python/

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be CPython ?

And does the Javascript need a browser client environment ?

If not, you can probably call [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) from [Jython](http://jython.org/).

( Note also that Jython release is only at 2.5.2 )

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can execute JavaScript from Python. I find the easiest way is through Python's bindings to the webkit library - [here is an example](http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/). In my experience selenium and spidermonkey are harder to get working.